# Duplicate number of tests with Resharper

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit, resharper, specflow

When I trigger the tests from ReSharper each test is added twice.

[image]

Tried multiple settings but I can't fix this issue. How can I remove the duplicated tests ? I'm using Webdriver with Specflow and Nunit. Resharper version is: 9.0 VS 2013

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Resharper -> Options
3. Go to Environment -> General
4. Clear cache
   [image: clear cache]
5. Go to Tools -> UnitTesting -> NUnit
6. Run tests with Specified NUnit Installation
7. Set path to latest NUnit version installed on machine
   [image: path]
8. Close VS.
9. Reopen VS.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that you have installed several Test-Adapters?

For example one (or more) via `Tools -> Extensions and Updates` and then again via your Project for example `References -> Manage NuGet Packages`

I ran into this issue once and after I uninstalled the ones in Project-References and all but one in Extensions and Updates everything worked ok again.

But one can only guess...